# How can I use list comprehension in following scenario?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

```
for key in enron_data.keys():
    if(enron_data[key]['email_address'] != 'NaN'):
        count += 1
print count
```

enron_data is 2d dictionary, containing names & value,key pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use len(..)

```
len( [v for v in enron_data.values() if v['email_address'] != 'NaN'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
print(sum(1 for key in enron_data.keys() if enron_data[key]["email_address"] != "NaN"))
```